# Invalid parameter configuration provided for $reader argument of Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList

Tags: magento2

I get this error when i make a ajax call in Magento 2:
Invalid parameter configuration provided for $reader argument of Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList

My controller

```
public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $data = $this->request->getParams();
    $currentdate = $this->date->gmtDate();
    $model = $this->aboncartFactory->create();
    $model->setData($data);
}
```

My Ajax call

```
function pushData() {
    var url = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('aboncart/index/insertorder'); ?>";
    var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname").value; //$("#billing_firstname").val();
    var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname").value; //$("#billing_lastname").val();
    var telephone = document.getElementsByName("telephone").value; //$("#billing_telephone").val();
    var email = document.getElementsByName("username").value; //$("#billing_email").val();
    var quote = "<?php echo $quoteId; ?>";
    var store = "<?php echo $storeId; ?>";
    var parameters = { 
        email: email,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        telephone: telephone,
        quote_id: quote,
        store_id: store
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: parameters,
        success: function(result)  {
          console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the ObjectManager from the controller and it's working again!